# Loopback: many-to-many relation, cannot get opposite

Tags: node.js, many-to-many, loopbackjs

I just started using [Loopback](https://loopback.io), and defined two models which should be bound by a trivial many-to-many relation.

The first model is `Customer`, the second model is `Pet`.

**Each Customer can have different Pets, and each Pet can be owned by different Customers.**

I create the relation using loopback-cli, and define it on the Customer model, having the Pet model as reference. The only change in the code is:

```
/* customer.json */
"relations": {
  "Pets": {
    "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
    "model": "Pet",
    "foreignKey": ""
  }
}
```

After this, I find a new set of REST endpoints for various actions of resources like `/customers/{customerId}/pets`.

How do I get also the opposite "side" of the relation, which in terms of REST api would be `/pets/{petId}/customers`?

I don't want to create a new relation, nor a new model. I just want to reuse the current MySQL table `CustomerPet` that already contains the information I need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to deal with a **hasAndBelongsToMany** relation is to create it in both directions with the cli tool:

- a *Pet* **hasAndBelongsToMany** *Customers*
- a *Customer* **hasAndBelongsToMany** *Pets*

This translates in having two different tables in the database: `PetCustomer` and `CustomerPet`.

Then, th REST api deals with both tables automatically when a new relation between two entities is created. There are two ways to do that:

- creating a new related entity, e.g. by POSTing a new pet to `/customers/{:customerId}/pets`
- creating a reference between two existing entities, e.g. by PUTting (an empty body is enough) to `/customers/{:customerId}/pets/rel/{:petId}`

I guess duplicating the database table holding the many-to-many relation is the price to have such a flexible and easy-to-use tool like loopback.